# How to create Rectangle With Gradient Color Stripes Border via CSS?

Tags: css, sass, border, linear-gradients

I want to create Round Edges Rectangle With **Gradient Color Stripes Border**.

I want to use the **img** tag or **div** tag to include the image and the Gradient Striped Border.

This is how it needs to look like:
[image]

I try to search around and i found that (SCSS) example: **https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/yujsz7wf/**

and i got this SCSS code:

```
.module {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 3%;
  > h2 {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  }
  > p {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  /*animation: widen 10s linear alternate infinite;*/
}

.stripe-1 {
  color: white;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 10px,
    #465298 10px,
    #465298 20px
  );
}
```

As you can see, that feature effect only **background** and not **border**.

How do I make that Rectangle to display Gradient Color Stripes in his Border Via CSS/SCSS?

Comment: Is the inner area (the white one) transparent?

Comment: No. It has image inside. I will use img or div tag to include the image in my page.

Comment: Will the image have transparency and do you need the exact same type of gradient or just some gradient?

Comment: I will start with some gradient

Comment: I wasn't able to get it similar to your image but maybe you (or some other user) can build on [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cp598srx/).

Comment: I'm not aware of any mthod of making this just a *border* ..a background would seem to be the most obvious option.

Comment: This is great but i need the colors to be exact as i display above. Ill try to play with it.

Comment: This is very simple, see my answer below using ```border-image```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to use a `linear-gradient` in the required pattern as `background-image` and put the required content on top of this background. This approach would work as long as the content, be it image or any text or whatever doesn't require to be transparent. The output is also responsive as can be seen by hovering on the element.

**With just the strips:** (a white layer is placed on top of the gradient to show only the strips)

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white), 
              linear-gradient(60deg, orange 0%, orange 3.5%, white 3.5%, white 7%, hotpink 7%, hotpink 10.5%, black 10.5%, black 14%, brown 14%, brown 17.5%, aqua 17.5%, aqua 21%, green 21%, green 25%, orange 25%, orange 28.5%, white 28.5%, white 32%, hotpink 32%, hotpink 35.5%, black 35.5%, black 39%, brown 39%, brown 42.5%, aqua 42.5%, aqua 46%, green 46%, green 50%, orange 50%, orange 53.5%, white 53.5%, white 57%, hotpink 57%, hotpink 60.5%, black 60.5%, black 64%, brown 64%, brown 67.5%, aqua 67.5%, aqua 71%, green 71%, green 75%, orange 75%, orange 78.5%, white 78.5%, white 82%, hotpink 82%, hotpink 85.5%, black 85.5%, black 89%, brown 89%, brown 92.5%, aqua 92.5%, aqua 96%, green 96%, green 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-origin: content-box, padding-box;
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}

/* just for demo */

div {
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**With image inside the** `div`:

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(60deg, orange 0%, orange 3.5%, white 3.5%, white 7%, hotpink 7%, hotpink 10.5%, black 10.5%, black 14%, brown 14%, brown 17.5%, aqua 17.5%, aqua 21%, green 21%, green 25%, orange 25%, orange 28.5%, white 28.5%, white 32%, hotpink 32%, hotpink 35.5%, black 35.5%, black 39%, brown 39%, brown 42.5%, aqua 42.5%, aqua 46%, green 46%, green 50%, orange 50%, orange 53.5%, white 53.5%, white 57%, hotpink 57%, hotpink 60.5%, black 60.5%, black 64%, brown 64%, brown 67.5%, aqua 67.5%, aqua 71%, green 71%, green 75%, orange 75%, orange 78.5%, white 78.5%, white 82%, hotpink 82%, hotpink 85.5%, black 85.5%, black 89%, brown 89%, brown 92.5%, aqua 92.5%, aqua 96%, green 96%, green 100%);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-origin: content-box, padding-box;
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}
img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
}
/* just for demo */

div, img {
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover, div:hover img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/250/nature/1' />
</div>
```

---

**With repeating linear gradient:** (thanks to [vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals) for creating the demo)

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(white,white), repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, orange 0%, orange 3.5%, white 3.5%, white 7%, hotpink 7%, hotpink 10.5%, black 10.5%, black 14%, brown 14%, brown 17.5%, aqua 17.5%, aqua 21%, green 21%, green 25%);
  background-attachment: padding-box, border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-origin: content-box, padding-box;
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}

/* just for demo */

div {
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The jagged edges are something that are tough to avoid when using angled gradients. They can be reduced by adjusting the color stop points.

Comment: This is great, but i dont want the full background to load. Only the strips.

Comment: @StackBuck: Once the image on top loads, the background won't be seen. There is no other way to do this. It can be done with `border-image` but it won't give you the curved (`border-radius`) effect.

Comment: This background seems ok to me :     background: repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, orange 0%, orange 3.5%, white 3.5%, white 7%, hotpink 7%, hotpink 10.5%, black 10.5%, black 14%, brown 14%, brown 17.5%, aqua 17.5%, aqua 21%, green 21%, green 25%);

Comment: I will give that a try in the morning when I get onto my PC @vals. If it works and you aren't planning to post an answer please feel free to edit my answer and add a version with the repeating gradient :)

Comment: @vals: Yes, it works. Wonderful and thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes. That exactly what i needed! I just change the colors to:   background: linear-gradient(white,white), repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, #e53f23 0%, #e53f23 3.5%, #0090d0 3.5%, #0090d0 7%, #fdb813 7%, #fdb813 10.5%, #8ec63f 10.5%, #8ec63f 14%, #e53f23 14%, #e53f23 17.5%, #0090d0 17.5%, #0090d0 21%, #fdb813 21%, #fdb813 25%);

Comment: Wonderful @StackBuck. Happy that I could help you (thanks to vals too) :)

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for this to be so convoluted, it takes two lines of CSS:

```
.module {
    border: 20px solid;
    border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#606dbc,#606dbc 10px,#465298 10px,#465298 20px) 20;
}
```

A fork of your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5k70jt5f/1/

Comment: border-radius doesn't affect border-image, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Found somthing that can be a key to that design. See here: **https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/jaca7sb4/**

Here is the source of the code: **http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/DKhkf**

CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;

}
div:before, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
div:before {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1abc9c 1%, #2ecc71 1%, #2ecc71 29%, #3498db 29%, #3498db 32%, #9b59b6 32%, #9b59b6 37%, #34495e 37%, #34495e 53%, #f1c40f 53%, #f1c40f 69%, #e67e22 69%, #e67e22 67%, #e74c3c 67%, #e74c3c 74%, #ecf0f1 74%, #ecf0f1 100%, #95a5a6 100%);
}
div:after {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1abc9c 10%, #2ecc71 10%, #2ecc71 12.5%, #3498db 12.5%, #3498db 28%, #9b59b6 28%, #9b59b6 35%, #34495e 35%, #34495e 60%, #f1c40f 60%, #f1c40f 69%, #e67e22 69%, #e67e22 83%, #e74c3c 83%, #e74c3c 88%, #ecf0f1 88%, #ecf0f1 96%, #95a5a6 96%);
}

div {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

However, i cant set it on the **right** and **left** side of the div. Only top and bottom effected.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, we can mask a repeating linear gradient background.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.stripe {
  --thickness: 10px;
  --stripe: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 0 0/100% var(--thickness) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 0 0/var(--thickness) 100% no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 0 100% / 100% var(--thickness) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 100% 0/ var(--thickness) 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #febf28 0 var(--stripe), #000 var(--stripe) calc(var(--stripe) * 2))
}

.original-gradient {
  margin-top: 20px;
  --stripe: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #febf28 0 var(--stripe), #000 var(--stripe) calc(var(--stripe) * 2))
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe"></div>
<div class="original-gradient"></div>
```